# show that $q$ and $r$ are unique when $r$ is less than or equal to zero.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Given $a$ and $b$ are integers. Suppose you are given $q$ and $r$ are integers such that
>
> $b = qa + r$ and $-a < r \leq 0$
>
> show that $q$ and $r$ are unique by using Euclidean remainder.

What I was confused about is: I know how I can prove when $r$ is greater than $0$ and less than $a$. But what happens when $r$ is less than or equal to $0$ and greater than $-a$? How would the solution be different?

Comment: If you can prove the uniqueness when $0\lt r\lt a$ where you implicitly assume $a\gt 0$, you can just take $p=-r$ and then prove the uniqueness of $q,p$ instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is an implicit assumption in your problem that $a > 0$.

**Hint:**  The Division Algorithm states that if $a$ and $b$ are integers, with $a > 0$, then there exist unique integers $q$ and $r$ such that $b = qa + r$ and $0 \leq r < a$.  If $r = 0$, we are done.  If $r \neq 0$, what happens if we replace $q$ by $q' = q + 1$?